# Angular 2: template not updating in test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-testing

I am just trying to make this work.

```
it('should have expected <h1> text', async(() => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const sectionEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("section"));

  spyOn(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance, "runMe");

  sectionEl.nativeElement.click();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.runMe).toHaveBeenCalled();

  expect(sectionEl.nativeElement.textContent).toBe("changed!");
```

So, the `runMe` function did not change the section's text, but the spy shows `runMe` was called.

Comment: can you edit your post to include code for your `runMe` function?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing a more complete example. But with clicking stuff, it usually involves asynchronous event handling. Therefore we need to wait for the event handling to complete. In a test, how we can do that is by calling `fixture.whenStable`, which returns a promise. We can continue the test when the promise resolves.

```
sectionEl.nativeElement.click();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.runMe).toHaveBeenCalled();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(sectionEl.nativeElement.textContent).toBe("changed!");
});
```

Comment: I tried this earlier in my own project, and it doesn't work. I also tried something like this in my cloned local copy of the angular 2 quickstart github repo and it does not work.

Comment: You should probably post a complete example for further help

Comment: peeskillet, I am trying to set up a Plunkr for this. Can you help me make TestBed work in src/test.spec.ts.

Comment: Here is the Plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/K0IyBnR8F4F7zOp6LETi?p=preview